# hadoop/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible

Tags: configuration, hadoop

At first i cannot let jobtrackers and tasktrackers run, then i replaced all ips like 10.112.57.243 with hdmaster in xml files, and changed mapred.job.tracker into hdfs:// one. Later i formated namenode while hadoop running, then it turned into a disaster. I found the error msg as the title in logs, then i tried even remove all in /tmp and hdfs tmp, then restart, it's still like this. So how can i get rid of this error and let namenode run again? Thanks a lot.

core-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
    <property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://hdmaster:50000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
     <value>/home/ubuntu/hadoop/tmp</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
    <description>Default block replication. The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created. The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.</description>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

hadoop-site.xml

```
    <configuration>

    <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/home/ubuntu/hadoop/tmp</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://hdmaster:50000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
      <value>hdfs://hdmaster:50001</value>
    </property>

    </configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
      <value>hdfs://hdmaster:50001</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>mapred.system.dir</name>
     <value>/home/ubuntu/hadoop/system</value>
     </property>
    <property>
      <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
     <value>/home/ubuntu/hadoop/var</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: I remembered it's after i lsof -i:500xx and killed that process.

Comment: it seems everything just got messed up badly. follow this link properly. hopefully you'll be able to do it. http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-configure-hadoop.html#.UZHj7kAW38s

Comment: Thank you, I've already started from scracth XD